# Multiplication of two 32 bit numbers using only 8 bit numbers

Tags: c, pointers, bit, multiplication

I saw this interview question online and can't find a good method other than the usual additive methods.
Any suggestions if this can be done quicker using some bitshift / recursion or something similar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitshifting would be natural part of a solution.

To multiply a value *a* by an eight-bit value *b*, for each 1 bit in *b*, add up all the values of *a* multiplied by *b* with all other bits set to 0. For example, `a * 10100001 = a * 10000000 + a * 00100000 + a * 00000001`.

Taking this further, suppose we want to multiply `11001011` by `0010000`, this is `11001011(bin) << 4(dec)`. Doing this on an eight-bit value gives you `10110000`. You have also lost `(8-4)=4` bits from the beginning. Hence you would also want to do `11001011(bin) >> 4(dec)` to get `00001100` as a carry into the next "8-bit column" (assuming that we are using 8 columns to represent a 64-bit answer).

Recursion would not really be necessary. All you'd need is a loop through the 4 bytes of the first 32-bit number, with another loop through the 4 bytes of the second number inside, multiplying each pair of bytes together in turn and adding it to your solution.